# Different execution plans depending on columns selected from CTE

Tags: performance, sql-server-2014, execution-plan, query-performance

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLEA(
ID NUMERIC(19,0) IDENTITY(1,1),
COLUMNA varchar(256) NOT NULL,
COLUMNB varchar(256) NOT NULL,
COLUMNC varchar(256)  NOT NULL,
COLUMND varchar(max)  NULL,
COLUMNE bigint  NOT NULL,
COLUMNF numberic(19,0),
CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
 COLUMNA ASC
)
) ON PRIMARY

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_COLUMNE_COLUMNF ON TABLEA(COLUMNE, COLUMNF)
```

I am running the following CTE.

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COLUMNE ORDER BY COLUMNE) AS rownum, 
COLUMNA, 
COLUMNB, 
COLUMNC, 
COLUMND, 
COLUMNE, 
COLUMNF
WHERE COLUMNF = 1 AND COLUMNE >= 1472738400000 AND COLUMNE <= 1475244000000
)
```

Now the question. When I run

```
SELECT TOP 30000 * FROM CTE
```

SQL does an index seek on the nonclustered index with a key lookup on the clustered and takes 3 to 4 seconds to complete.

However, if I run the below SQL does a clustered index scan and completes in about 15 seconds.

```
SELECT TOP 30000 COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMNC, COLUMND, COLUMNE, COLUMNF FROM CTE
```

To give some idea of distribution of values:

- The table contains approx. ~13.7 million rows.
- COLUMNF always has a value of 1.
- Excluding the TOP 30000 the query returns 474296 rows, of which there are 92683 have a rownum value of 2 or higher.

Can anyone provide any insight as to why SQL would pick a different execution plan for the two queries?

Execution Plans

SELECT by column name
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyJZeZlC

SELECT *
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1BQgZl0

Comment: Remember that `TOP (N)` *without* and `ORDER BY` - [the order of the resulting rows is non-deterministic even though it may seem otherwise.](http://michaeljswart.com/2013/09/without-order-by-you-cant-depend-on-the-order-of-results/)

Comment: If you get an estimated plan for `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable WHERE COLUMNF = 1 AND COLUMNE >= 1472738400000 AND COLUMNE <= 1475244000000` how many rows does it estimate will match the predicate and go into the aggregate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plan *without* row number is below.

[image]

This is assigned a cost of `44.866`.

You have a `TOP` without `ORDER BY` so SQL Server just needs to scan the clustered index and as soon as it finds the first 30,000 rows matching the predicate it can stop.

The table has 13,283,300 rows. A full clustered index scan is costed at `730.467 + 14.6118 = 745.0788` but this gets scaled down to `43.9392` because of the `TOP`.

Applying the same scaling of `5.9%` to the number of rows in the table this would imply that SQL Server estimates that it will only have to scan `783,350` rows before it finds 30,000 matching the `WHERE` and can stop scanning.

NB: You say that only `474,296` rows match this predicate in the whole table but `508,747` are estimated to. That means that on average one in every `26.1` (`13283300/508747`) rows is assumed to match the filter. So it is estimated that `30,000 * 26.1` rows ( = `783K`) will be read.

When you select `*` that means that the `rownum` column must be calculated. the plan for this is below. It is costed at `69.1185`

[image]

You have an index on `COLUMNE` that can be seeked into. This satisfies the range predicate on `COLUMNE >= 1472738400000 AND COLUMNE <= 1475244000000` and also supplies the required ordering for your row numbering.

However it does not cover the query and lookups are needed to return the missing columns. The plan estimates that there will be 30,000 such lookups. There may in fact be more as the predicate on `COLUMNF = 1` may mean some rows are discarded after being looked up (though not in this case as you say COLUMNF always has a value of 1).

If the row numbering plan was to use a clustered index scan it would need to be a full scan followed by a sort of all rows matching the predicate. `69.1185` is considerably cheaper than the `745.0788 + sort cost` so the plan with lookups is chosen.

You say that the plan with lookups is in fact 5 times faster than the clustered index scan. Likely a much greater proportion of the clustered index needed to be read to find 30,000 matching rows than was assumed in the costings. You are on SQL Server 2014 SP1 CU5. On SQL Server 2014 SP2 the *actual* execution plan now has a new attribute [Actual Rows Read](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3107397) which would tell you how many rows it did actually read. On previous versions you can use [`OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 9130)`](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2012/12/06/my-new-favourite-traceflag.aspx) to see the same information.

Comment: Thank you Martin, This is exactly what I was hoping to get from this question. You are correct that the clustered index scan would ahve to read the majority of the table before it found the 30000 matches. Adding the ORDER BY COLUMNE allowed the query to return in 3 seconds. I will be going through your comments and the new execution plan to compare the differences.

Comment: @Adam - I'm still doing a bit of experimenting as to whether the `730.467 + 14.6118` becoming a subtree cost of only `43.9392` is purely because of the `TOP` or whether there might be some other reason as well (e.g. costs of reading off row content). How many rows does it estimate will match the predicate without the `TOP`?

Comment: It estimate 508747 rows. I'm happy to provide any information you need.

Comment: @Adam - That adds up actually. Assuming even distribution then `13283300/508747` means on average every 26.1 rows match the predicate. Multiply that by  30,000 and you get 783K. In reality the distribution may well not be even and it might have to read significantly more than that.